# A question about the vanishing of motivic cohomology in negative Tate twist

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motives, motivic-cohomology, motivic-homotopy

Let $DM_{\text{gm}}$ be the category of Voevodsky´s geometric motives. Let $p,q\in \mathbb{Z}$ be integers with $p<0$.

Is it true that 
$$\text{Hom}_{DM_{\text{gm}}}(M_{\text{gm}}(X),\mathbb{Z}(p)[q])=0,$$
where $M(X)$ is the motive of a smooth scheme $X$ over a field $k$ and $\mathbb{Z}(p)$ is the Tate motive?

Comment: By definition, negative Tate twists do not exist in the category of effective motives, so that this question does not even make sense.

Comment: Dear @Denis-CharlesCisinski, thank you for your answer. I was trying to understand the last part of the first point of Lemma 7.1.1 in https://www.uni-due.de/~bm0032/publ/Azumaya24.pdf

Comment: If you drop the effectiveness, this vanishing makes sense, does hold, and is used in the proof of the second assertion of Lemma 7.1.1 of loc. cit. indeed.

Comment: @Denis-CharlesCisinski. I see now. So, the vanishing, droping the effectiveness, follows by construction? Or do they invoke some well known result?

Comment: This vanishing property does not hold by construction but is well known indeed.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an easy way to see this (which is more or less an elaboration of Mikhail's answer):

Suppose $i > 0$ and $n\in \mathbb Z$. We have the Thom isomorphism
$$
H^n(X, \mathbb Z(-i)) \cong H^{n+2i}_X(\mathbb A^i_X, \mathbb Z(0)).
$$
Weight $0$ motivic cohomology is just Zariski cohomology, so
$$
H^n(X,\mathbb Z(0)) = \begin{cases} \mathbb Z^{\pi_0(X)} & \text{if }n=0,\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$
Now the long exact sequence for cohomology with support shows that $H^*_X(\mathbb A^i_X,\mathbb Z(0))=0$.

Answer (score 2):

I will sketch a proof.

It suffices to prove that there are only zero morphisms from $M_{\text{gm}}(X)(1)$ into $\mathbb{Z}[q]$ for any smooth $X$ and $q\in \mathbb{Z}$. The latter statement easily follows from the fact that the  $\mathbb{Z}$ is a birational sheaf (with transfers); see Lemma 2.3.2(b) of "Birational Motives, II: Triangulated Birational Motives" by Bruno Kahn and Ramdorai Sujatha.